# Debugging touchesEnded NOT being called when swiping in 1 direction only

Tags: objective-c, touch, uitouch

Totally stumped in debugging a simple swipe movement for my application. When I swipe in a left direction, I correctly get a touchesEnded message-method call.

BUT, if I drag in the other direction, touchesEnded does NOT get called.

Anyone have a clue as to why this might be?
I'm using a TapDetectingView as my view for my viewController class. And user intraction and multiple touch are both enabled for this view in IB.

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues too, using GestureRecognizers and touchesEnded on a single view.
My problem was, that I was either able to detect swipes OR touches when using GestureRecognizers only.
What I ended up doing, was using SwipeGestureRecognizers to detect swipes and the touchesEnded Method for Taps. 
Using TapGestureRecognizers and SwipeGestureRecognizers on the same view didn't work.

Comment: I can't use the new GestureRecognizer mthods, because I need to calculate the velocity of the actual swipe.

Comment: ok, sorry about that i could't figure out your intentions by reading your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to capture the `touchesEnded` on a swipe gesture try checking for `touchesCancelled`.  I handle my swipe ends via the `touchesCancelled` and then call `touchesEnded` from within that method.  For some reason `touchesEnded` is only called via single taps and long presses but not swipes.  The nice thing is that you get a timestamp and coordinates to use for figuring out acceleration.

Comment: `touchesCancelled` is called when the system cancels a touch, like when a phone call comes in. `touchesEnded` is definitely called for swipes.